# Redis session disable_locking to true

Tags: php, session, redis, magento2, stackexchange.redis

We are using Redis session storage from (AWS) for one of our Magento2 Application and facing issue in setting the custom session data.

As a solution there is one property in the Redis configuration file disable_locking by default its false when we change that to true our system works fine.

So want to understand the Pros and Cons of using this property to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable session locking , i believe from aws configuration - Because the locking is actually done at application level in how the application is utilizing the locks

Comment: The `disable_locking` that they were asking about is option in Magento's app/etc/env.php, not AWS configuration.